# How to locate an element with div format in Selenium. getting error Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is the code :

```
<div class="footer-bottom-left">
    <div class="campaignUser">Campaign User</div>
    <div class="callLogLookUp">Call Log Look Up</div>
</div>
```

I have tried the below code in selenium:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='footer-bottom-left'].//div[@class='callLogLookUp']")).click();`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed dash in class name. Also you need to remove second dot (first is also not required). So instead of

```
.//div[@class='footer-bottomleft'].//div[@class='callLogLookUp']
```

try

```
//div[@class='footer-bottom-left']//div[@class='callLogLookUp']
```

You might also need to implement [ExplicitWait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='footer-bottom-left']//div[@class='callLogLookUp']"))).click();
```

Comment: Tried : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='footer-bottom-left']//div[@class='callLogLookUp']")).click();     .. But it didnt worked

Comment: @RaishulAlam , Try updated answer. By the way are you sure that that `div` is clickable? It doesn't look like clickable element

Comment: It worked . The updated code worked with no issues.. Thanks

Comment: The second double slash `//` is not needed... it can/should be `/`, i.e. //div[@class='footer-bottom-left']/div[@class='callLogLookUp']. This would be so much cleaner as a CSS selector ... `div.footer-bottom-left > div.callLogLookUp`. :)

Comment: @JeffC , yes, but in this current case it doesn't really matter as parent `div` has no descendants, but children only. Also `div.footer-bottom-left > div.callLogLookUp` is not really the same as `//div[@class='footer-bottom-left']/div[@class='callLogLookUp']`, but `//div[contains(@class, 'footer-bottom-left')]/div[contains(@class, 'callLogLookUp')]`. CSS selector for the same should be `div[class='footer-bottom-left'] > div[class='callLogLookUp']`

Comment: Well it actually does matter... if in the future the children of the parent DIV (or child DIVs) change. Why would you look for all descendants when there are only children?

Comment: You are correct about the two selectors not being exactly the same but why would you make it more restrictive by adding exact string matches for the class names? Would you want it to fail if another class is added to either element? I would suspect not. That's one of the big advantages of CSS selectors, you get that extra flexibility without all the extra syntax and string matching (that may match other classes unexpectedly, e.g. `contains(,.'footer-bottom')` would match both `<div class="footer-bottom">` and `<div class="footer-bottom-left">`... maybe the second one unexpectedly.

Comment: @Jeffc , I don't really think that it make sense to create two embedded `div` nodes with exactly the same class names, but as I said: it doesn't matter for this case, but if DOM changed, there might be nuances...

Comment: @JeffC , there might be several good selectors, but OP used XPath that was not valid and OP asked for XPath solution. I've just pointed on mistakes OP did. You can provide another solution with explanation about why OP should not use XPath, but use CSS selector instead :)

Comment: Agreed... I just figured I would put it in a comment here as an alternative rather than a separate answer.